# Add HTML elements under While php loop

Tags: php, html

I want to add a menu with numbers like 1 - 2 - 3. And I'm using php to get the numbers but when I add the menu's tags, the page starts to load to forever

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM science";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$no =  mysqli_num_rows($result);
$qu = $no / 25;
$page = 0;
while($page < round($qu)) {
$page++; 
}
$p = round($qu) - $page;
if($p > 0 and $p < 0.5) {
$page++;
}
while($PageNum < $page) {
?>
<ul class='pageUl'>
<li class='pages'><span class='spanPage' onclick='changeQ()'><?php $PageNum ?></span></li>
<?php
}
echo "</ul>";
```

I tried to use echo "the html tag". I know there is no difference but it didn't work also.

Comment: What is the value of `$PageNum` variable.

Comment: get a printr or vardump inside a loop and see what it prints for the variables in loop condition, you'll most likely get to the reason easily, and find out the loop is in fact infinite, and while you don't modify PageNum value, it's mostl likely the direct reason.. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized the `$PageNum` variable.

So, while loop is looping infinite times.

I think `$PageNum` should be calculated as number page pages.

Considering you are showing 25 records per page, calculate number of pages depending upon number of records.

```
$no =  mysqli_num_rows($result);
$PageNum = $qu = ceil($no / 25);
```